# From where to download the Izpack native launcher?

Tags: java, windows-installer, izpack

I am trying to create the installer for my java web application. I need to create a exe which will install bundled java (if not already installed on the system), postgresql and tomcat.

For this we have decided to use the izpack http://izpack.org/. But on their download page I can not find the native launcher.

As mentioned on their website, ***IzPack 4 came along with a simple Windows native launcher that could check for the presence of a Java Runtime, and install it if need be. This launcher is currently not supported in IzPack 5 due to a missing maintainer for this feature***

I was using below tutorial

[Building Native Windows Installers with IzPack Native Launcher](http://www.javalobby.org/articles/izpack/)

Answer (score 0):

You can find IzPack Native Launcher on GitHub : https://github.com/jponge/izpack-launcher.